# Hash Tag '#' not shown in dial pad react-native (Phone number)

Tags: react-native, phone-number

[Dial-pad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlqAp.jpg)

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  phoneNumber = 'tel:${*400#}';
}
```

Comment: try change this `'tel:${*400}+'#''`

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replaced # by %23 and solved..